# CKAN Dataset Upload Page giving a Server

Tags: upload, dataset, ckan

When creating a dataset you are required to either upload the csv or xml file containing the data or link to the data file located on a server. When I attempt to upload a csv or xml file the upload process starts but the page eventually crash with the following message.

**Server Error
An internal server error occurred**

also see below error in /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log

```
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:18.934269 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:18,934 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  / render time 0.169 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:21.217534 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:21,217 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:23.832089 2015] [:error] [pid 1244] 2015-08-10 19:08:23,831 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /user/admin render time 0.413 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:24.430716 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:24,430 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:26.858892 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:26,858 WARNI [ckan.lib.maintain] Function get_action() in module ckan.lib.helpers has been deprecated and will be removed in a later release of ckan. helpers.get_action() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of CKAN. Instead, please use the extra_vars param to render() in your controller to pass results from action functions to your templates.
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:27.080089 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:27,079 WARNI [ckan.lib.maintain] Function get_action() in module ckan.lib.helpers has been deprecated and will be removed in a later release of ckan. helpers.get_action() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of CKAN. Instead, please use the extra_vars param to render() in your controller to pass results from action functions to your templates.
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:27.190495 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:27,190 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dataset/grocery-prices render time 0.551 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:27.664450 2015] [:error] [pid 1244] 2015-08-10 19:08:27,664 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:30.847326 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:30,847 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dataset/edit/grocery-prices render time 0.405 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:31.373743 2015] [:error] [pid 1244] 2015-08-10 19:08:31,373 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:34.934102 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:08:34,933 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dataset/new render time 0.091 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:35.451324 2015] [:error] [pid 1244] 2015-08-10 19:08:35,451 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dataset/new_resource/grocery-prices render time 0.412 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:36.271926 2015] [:error] [pid 1244] 2015-08-10 19:08:36,271 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:08:49.310932 2015] [:error] [pid 1244] 2015-08-10 19:08:49,310 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/2/util/resource/format_autocomplete render time 0.006 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:09:11.244287 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] /usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py:79: SAWarning: Usage of the 'related attribute set' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
[Mon Aug 10 19:09:11.244325 2015] [:error] [pid 1243]   sess._flush_warning("related attribute set")
[Mon Aug 10 19:09:11.518274 2015] [:error] [pid 1243] 2015-08-10 19:09:11,518 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dataset/new_resource/grocery-prices render time 0.176 seconds
[Mon Aug 10 19:09:11.975593 2015] [:error] [pid 1244] 2015-08-10 19:09:11,975 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
```

Not sure what caused this error and the logs do not provide enough information. The file is not deposited to the dataset directory location.

Using CKAN 2.3 on a Ubuntu 14.04 server running apache2

Comment: Do you have any information in the logs? Without it, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I added the error log.

Comment: that log doesn't show any `ERROR`s though. Look in your apache config to see where errors are logged to and grep for ERROR to see what the "Server Error" was.